# Error while Building Docker Container using linux command on MacOS - "must use ASL logging (which requires CGO) if running as root"

Tags: docker, macos

I installed the Docker desktop application on my Mac (Apple Silicon). With all the necessary docker files from a cloned project, I ran this command

```
sudo docker-compose up --build
```

It asked for my computer password but then threw this error

```
20:34:16 must use ASL logging (which requires CGO) if running as root
[+] Running 0/0
 ⠋ postgres Pulling                                                                                                                         0.0s 
error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out: ``
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run the Docker daemon as a non-root user:

```golang
docker-compose up --build
```

That is why the password was requested.
As you have Docker Desktop installed on your Mac M1 there should be no reason to run as root.
However, if there is a requirement to have privileged permission to run Docker Desktop, then follow this guide:

- [Run the Docker daemon as a non-root user (Rootless mode)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/)